# Como fazer textos ocultos aparecerem ao expandir um menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu, texto

tenho uma dúvida,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver na imagem, essa é uma parte de um site que o cliente pediu. Como eu posso fazer esse menu onde você clica e ele expande e mostra o texto oculto? E ainda tem aquele efeito deslizante?

Eu vou precisar fazer esse mesmo efeito inclusive para versões de celular.
Se precisar eu coloco o código que já fiz. Só para vcs saberem, eu ainda não fiz o círculo nem coloquei esse triangulo no projeto ainda.

Comment: você usa javascript/jquery?

Comment: Eu não sei usar. Nunca usei Tb. Meu código está puramente em HTML, CSS e PHP

Comment: Enrico coloque o que vc já tem de código que facilita para te dar uma resposta que será útil para vc. Vc quer que a pessoa possa abrir todos os textos se quiser, ou vc quer que ela só possa abrir 1 por vez, tipo se abrir um tem que fechar o outro?

Comment: Olha se você quiser usar *JQuery* é fácil faze isso, veja esse exemplo no site *w3schools*: ***https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slideup_slidedown***

Comment: hugocsl - tanto faz, na vdd, pode deixar todos os itens abertos. O que eu preciso é que a pessoa clique naquele triangulo, faça o efeito dele girando, depois o conteúdo expande. Aí se não interessar mais para o usuário, ele pode fechar essa guia. Mas pode deixar sim todos os itens abertos, isso é indiferente.

Comment: Coloque o código porque isso vai depender da estrutura do HTML para definir seletores etc.

Comment: Cara vc está usando algum Framework tipo Materialize ou Bootstrap?

Comment: Não estou usando Framework, eu uso o Visual Studio como editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que isso atenda mais ou menos o que você precisa

```js
$(function (){
  $("body").ready(function(){
    $(".sessao").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("expandir")){
        $(this).removeClass("expandir");
      }else{
        $(this).addClass("expandir");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "arial";
}

.sessao{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.sessao:before{
  content: "";
  height: 30px; width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: inherit;
}

.sessao:after{
  content: "";
  height: 30px; width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: inherit;
}

.titulo{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.expandir{
  height: 500px;
}

.expandir .conteudo{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.expandir .titulo{
  opacity: 0;
}

.conteudo{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sessao" style="background-color: red;">
  <div class="titulo">teste</div>
  <div class="conteudo">teste bla bla lba</div>
</div>
<div class="sessao" style="background-color: green;">
  <div class="titulo">teste</div>
  <div class="conteudo">teste bla bla lba</div>
</div>
<div class="sessao" style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="titulo">teste</div>
  <div class="conteudo">teste bla bla lba</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição para se adequar exatamente ao seu problema, ainda ta bem simples, mas a base está aí!

Comment: Obrigado Rocigno, vou testar e depois retorno os resultados aqui!

Comment: Rocigno - eu testei o seu código, a estilização ficou igual, com o texto e tudo, mas justamente a animação de expandir o menu que vem do javascript não funcionou ainda :/ será que fiz algo errado?

Comment: Insere essa parte no header da sua página: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Cara funcionou, os menus expandem e recolhem, como eu queria, no entanto, o texto não "some" quando o menu é recolhido. Ele fica por cima dos outros textos, fica uma bagunça.

Comment: Colocou essa parte na folha de estilos?
`.expandir{
  height: 500px;
}

.expandir .conteudo{
  display: block;
}

.expandir .titulo{
  display: none;
}

.conteudo{
  display: none;
}` 
É essa parte que faz os textos aparecerem e sumirem

Comment: Mano, que falta de atenção! era só criar uma classe "conteudo" e envolver todo o código de texto das divs. Só ficou um último detalhe: Quando vc clica para expandir, o texto ele aparece de repente, e quando vc clica para recolher, ele desaparece de repente. Eu queria algo como, o texto for aparecendo e desaparecendo, conforme o menu for expandindo/recolhendo.

Comment: Certo, fiz algumas alterações na resposta... alterei as classes `.titulo` e `.conteudo`, ao invés de "apagar" a div estou somente tirando a opacidade e adicionando o efeito de transição. Não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer isso, mas pelo menos funciona :D

Comment: Olha, funcionou, e obrigado por isso! Só acho q ficou meio estranho... Mas enfim... :D

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma opção feita apenas com CSS. Essa resposta apenas contem alguns elementos e estilos que podem te ajudar. Vc precisa ver a melhor forma de adaptar seu conteúdo dentro dos `collapses` para eles não extrapolarem os limites do *container*

Usei uma regra de CSS que usar um `chackbox` escondido que quando é marcada clicando na seta que na verdade é uma `label` vc muda a altura da `div`. O efeito dela aumentando e recolhendo e feito com o `transition`

Como falei é apenas um exemplo que as vezes vc pode aproveitar a ideia.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pai {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pai .filhos {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.pai .filhos label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pai .filhos label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 15px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleY(-1);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
#id1:checked + div > label::before, #id2:checked + div > label::before, #id3:checked + div > label::before {
  bottom: 15px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleY(1);
}
/* aqui vc controla a altura que a div vai ter quando aberta */
#id1:checked + div, #id2:checked + div, #id3:checked + div  {
  height: 100px;
}
.filho1, .filho1 label {
  background-color: #f00;
  z-index: 3;
}

.filho2, .filho2 label {
  background-color: #0f0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.filho3, .filho3 label {
  background-color: #00f;
  z-index: 1;
}
.pai > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 
  <div class="pai">
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="" id="id1">
    <div class="filhos filho1">
      123
      <label for="id1"></label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="" id="id2">
    <div class="filhos filho2">
      456
      <label for="id2"></label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="" id="id3">
    <div class="filhos filho3">
      789
      <label for="id3"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aos interessados estou colocando aqui o código CSS, seguido o HTML referente a essa parte:

```css
div.bloco4{                                                      /*  div que envolve a quarta parte do site  */
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;

}

div.parte1, .parte2, .parte3, h2{                                /*  personalização geral do h2 das 3 divs dentro do bloco 4 */
    font-family: 'Reem Kufi', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
}

div.parte1, .parte2, .parte3, p{                                  /*  personalização geral do p das 3 divs dentro do bloco 4 */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: center;
}

div.parte1{                                                       /*  personalização da primeira div do bloco 4 */
    background-color: rgb(245, 156, 47);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 1;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

}

div.fund1{                                                        /*  configuração para a div 1 flutuar na parte esquerda do site */
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

div.parte1 p#textofund1{                                          /*  personalização do p do primeiro texto da div 1 */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.parte1 p#texto-coluna1{                                       /*  personalização do p da coluna da esquerda da div 1 */
    padding-left: 30%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
}

div.lado p#texto-coluna2{                                          /*  personalização do p da coluna à direita da div 1 */
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

div.parte2{                                                        /*  personalização da segunda div do bloco 4 */
    background-color: rgb(240, 74, 51);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

}

div.fund2{                                                         /*  configuração para a div 2 flutuar na parte esquerda do site */
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
}

div.parte2 p#textofund2{                                           /*  personalização do p do primeiro texto da div 2 */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.parte2 p#texto-coluna3{                                         /*  personalização do p da coluna da esquerda da div 2 */
    padding-left: 30%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
}

div.parte2 p#texto-coluna4{                                        /*  personalização do p da coluna à direita da div 2 */
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

div.parte3{                                                        /*  personalização da terceira div do bloco 4 */
    background-color: rgb(03, 163, 87);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 1;
    padding-bottom: 1px;


}

div.parte3 p#texto-ensmedio{                                           /*  personalização do p do primeiro texto da div 2 */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.parte3 p#texto-coluna5{                                         /*  personalização do p da coluna da esquerda da div 2 */
    padding-left: 30%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
}

div.parte3 p#texto-coluna6{                                        /*  personalização do p da coluna à direita da div 2 */
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="bloco4" id="bloco4">
    
        <div class="parte1">
            <h2>FUNTAMENTAL I</h2>
                <p id="textofund1">Nesta etapa, os estudantes do 1º ano ao 5º ano vão experimentar 
                o maior número de ferramentas e formas de aprendizagem para descobrirem suas 
                aptidões e preferências.
                </p>

        <div class="fund1">
            <p id="texto-coluna1">
                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>PERÍODO ACADÊMICO</font> <br> (7h20 às 13h00) <br>
                <br>Máximo de 15 estudantes por sala
                <br>Educação bilíngüe [logo YouZ]
                <br>Avaliações multifocais
                <br>Espaços de aprendizagem
                <br>Vivências cooperativas
                <br>Projetos pedagógicos <br><br>

                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Currículo</font>
                <br>Práticas de autoconhecimento
                <br>Educação financeira
                <br>Língua Portuguesa
                <br>Produção de texto
                <br>Matemática
                <br>Inglês
                <br>Ciências
                <br>História
                <br>Geografia
                <br>Educação Física
                <br>Arte
                <br>Filosofia
                <br>
            </p>
    </div>

    <div class="lado">
            <p id="texto-coluna2">
                <font style='font-weight:bold;'> PERÍODO AMPLIADO </font> <br> (13h00 às 19h00)<br>
                 O Período Ampliado concentra atividades divididas em três bases temáticas: <br><br>

                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>EXPRESSÃO E CRIATIVIDADE </font>
                <br>Criatividade
                <br>Teatro
                <br>Artes plásticas
                <br>Oratória
                <br><br>

                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>CORPO E MOVIMENTO </font> 
                <br>Práticas desportivas
                <br>Artes marciais
                <br>Dança
                <br>Jogos/Brincar
                <br><br>

                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>VIDA SAUDÁVEL </font> 
                <br>Práticas meditativas
                <br>Sustentabilidade
                <br>Bem-estar
                <br>Nutrição
                <br>
            </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="parte2">
            <h2>FUNDAMENTAL II</h2>
                <p id="textofund2">Nesta etapa, os estudantes do 6º ano ao 9º ano vão explorar conteúdos 
               acadêmicos e alternativos para ampliar sua bagagem de conhecimentos múltiplos.
                </p>
            
     <div class="fund2">
            <p id="texto-coluna3">
                <font style='font-weight:bold;'>PERÍODO ACADÊMICO</font> <br> (7h00 às 12h40) <br>
                <br> Máximo de 20 estudantes por sala
                <br> Ênfase no estudo de idiomas
                <br> Avaliações multifocais
                <br> Espaços de aprendizagem
                <br> Vivências cooperativas
                <br> Projetos de empreendedorismo
                <br>
            </p>
     </div>

     <div class="lado2">
            <p id="texto-coluna4">
             <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Currículo</font>
                <br>Língua Portuguesa
                <br>Produção de texto
                <br>Matemática
                <br>Educação financeira
                <br>Ciências 
                <br>História
                <br>Geografia
                <br>Arte
                <br>Educação Física
                <br>Inglês
                <br>Espanhol
                <br>Mandarim 
                <br>Iniciação à Física Quântica
                <br>Filosofia
            </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="parte3">
        <h2>ENSINO MÉDIO</h2>
            <p id="texto-ensmedio">
            Nesta etapa, os estudantes da 1ª à 3ª série do Ensino Médio vão aprofundar
             os conteúdos de acordo com o Exame Nacional do Ensino Médio (Enem).
            </p>
    <div class"primeira parte">
        <p id="texto-coluna5">
            <font style='font-weight:bold;'>PERÍODO ACADÊMICO </font> <br> (7h00 às 12h40 – 3 dias da semana) <br> (7h00 às 17h40 – 2 dias da semana) <br>
            <br>Máximo de 25 estudantes por sala
            <br>Projeto de vida
            <br>Empreendedorismo
            <br>Espaços de aprendizagem
            <br>Vivências cooperativas
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class"segunda-parte">
        <p id="texto-coluna6">
            <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Currículo</font>
            <br>Linguagens e Códigos
            <br>Literatura
            <br>Gramática
            <br>Produção de Texto
            <br>Arte
            <br>Educação Física
            <br>

            <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Ciências da Natureza e Matemática</font>
            <br>Geometria
            <br>Álgebra
            <br>Educação Financeira
            <br>Biologia
            <br>Física
            <br>Física Quântica
            <br>Química
            <br>

            <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Ciências Humanas</font>
            <br>História
            <br>Geografia
            <br>Filosofia
            <br>Sociologia
            <br>

            <font style='font-weight:bold;'>Línguas estrangeiras</font>
            <br>Inglês
            <br>Espanhol
            <br>Mandarim
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```